# Add/Delete object while offline triggers cloud function when going online. How to avoid cloud function to add data on empty path?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When I'm offline, if I add an object to a path where a cloud function is listening, and then I delete it while still offline, when going online, Firebase servers will receive the object creation, then right after its deletion.
The problem is that it will trigger, on creation, a cloud function. This cloud function will catch some data at another path and will add that data in the object that was created. But because the object was deleted while offline, it ends up being deleted. But the cloud function will recreate it (partially) when adding the data it went to grab somewhere else.

Because I don't want to have to track every single object I create/delete, I thought about checking if the object would still exist right before saving that data. The problem is that when I do so, the object still exist but by the time I save the data into it, it doesn't exist anymore.

What are my options? I thought about adding a 0.5s **sleep** but I don't think it's the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's not much you can do on the client app to help this situation.  Everything you do to compensate for this will be in Cloud Functions.

Second of all, you have to assume that events could be delivered out of order.  Deletes could be processed by Cloud Functions before creates.  If your code does not handle this case, you can expect inconsistency.

You said "I don't want to have to track every single object I create/delete", but the fact of the matter is that this is the best option if you want consistent handling of events that could happen out of order.  There is no easy way out of this situation if you're using Cloud Functions.  On top of that, your functions should be idempotent, so they can handle events that could be delivered more than once.

One alternative is to avoid making changes to documents, and instead push "command" objects to Cloud Functions that tell it the things that should change.  This might help slightly, but you should also assume that these commands could arrive out of order.

This is all part of the downside of serverless backends.  The upside is that you don't have to set up, manage, and deallocate server instances.  But your code has to be resilient to these issues.

Comment: Thanks Doug for your answer. Because you mentioned `documents`, first I wanted to clarify that I'm working with the RTDB and not Firestore. Regarding the order of events, I thought that when using mobile SDKs, all the events would be delivered to Firebase servers in the order they were created. If that's not the case, how can it know that Object1 was created if it tries to delete it first on the server? My function is somehow idempotent as it's triggered ONLY `onCreate` on a specific field that is never deleted except when deleting the whole object. So it's called only once per object.

Comment: There is no ordering guarantee whatsoever.  I mentioned that.  The behavior is the same for Cloud Firestore and Realtime Database.  I think you might misunderstand what idempotent means.